# How to execute a command when leaving the 'fugitiveblame' window?

Tags: autocmd, plugin-fugitive

When executing `:Gblame`, it opens up a window for the blame information.  When close that window with `q`, I want to execute `wincmd =`

I've tried the following, they don't seem to work:

```
autocmd BufLeave fugitiveblame wincmd =
autocmd BufLeave *.fugitiveblame wincmd =
autocmd WinLeave fugitiveblame wincmd =
autocmd WinLeave *.fugitiveblame wincmd =
```

This is also an issue with the `ctrlsf` plugin.  I would like to do the same thing.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: I guess what I'm after is the ability to re-equalize the window sizes after closing the blame or ctrlsf windows.

Comment: You could try [`QuitPre`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#QuitPre).

Comment: @Tumbler41 I don't think it would work, doesn't that get called *before* `:q` actually closes the window?  If I equalize the windows at that point, they'll be un-equalized after the blame window closes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not exactly as requested, but it seems to work:

```
autocmd FileType fugitiveblame nnoremap <buffer> q :q<CR>wincmd =
```

So this will work only if you close Gblame buffer with <kbd>q</kbd>